# Can someone explain how this state update is resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I've been learning ReactJs and I wrote these lines:

```
  handlerClick(i) {
    this.setState(
      (state) => (state.squares = [...state.squares, (state.squares[i] = "X")])
    );
  }
```

Now, I know whats happening but I'm confused with how this is working, the order that each operation is being executed...

Comment: Eek!  Do not assign to `state.squares`.  (Do not mutate state)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the order of operations, everything to the right of an assignment operator is evaluated before the assignment takes place, so every usage of `state` in the expression to the right of `=`, refers to `state` before any assignment occurs.

---

Regarding proper usage of setState, you shouldn't assign to your old state, but rather return an entirely new object:

```js
handlerClick(i) {
  this.setState((state) => {
    const squares = [...state.squares];
    squares[i] = "X";
    return {...state, squares };
  });
}
```

Or, equivalently:

```js
handlerClick(i) {
  const squares = [...this.state.squares];
  squares[i] = "X";
  this.setState({...this.state, squares});
}
```

Comment: I was following this react guide https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html, down at "State Updates May Be Asynchronous"

Comment: Read it carefully though - It doesn't tell you to mutate the state; rather, a new object is constructed *from* `this.state` and passed to `setState`, which is simply another way of doing what I've done above